# send dialog failing on certain URLs

Tags: javascript, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, send

Using the Javascript SDK, the "send" dialog fails on certain URLs - take for example the following two links:

this one sends...

https://fbapps.15letters.com/YMCA/idea.php?id=1

this one gives me back the "Oops" dialog, saying "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.":

https://fbapps.15letters.com/YMCA/idea.php?id=25

The error I get back in the hit to uiserver.php (on facebook, not my own file of that name, of course) is:

for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357010,"errorSummary":"Oops","errorDescription":"Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.","payload":{"secure":true},"css":["FYoJj","KMyLD"],"js":["H9Hzx"],"onload":["PlatformFeedForm.blockLinks();"],"bootloadable":{"Dialog":{"resources":["3xwnY","FYoJj"],"module":true},"IframeShim":{"resources":["3xwnY","zjBXO"],"module":true},"json":{"resources":[],"module":true,"runWhenReady":true},"ErrorSignal":{"resources":["3xwnY","cNca2"],"module":true},"DOM":{"resources":["3xwnY"],"module":true},"HTML":{"resources":["3xwnY"],"module":true}},"resource_map":{"FYoJj":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y7/r/kbsFfWnz6Xt.css"},"KMyLD":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y8/r/vSCLbQo-oPv.css"},"H9Hzx":{"type":"js","src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y4/r/oFH0t8Tars2.js"},"3xwnY":{"type":"js","src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/kuMtdEABYch.js"},"zjBXO":{"type":"js","src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yn/r/av97v2Qooev.js"},"cNca2":{"type":"js","src":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yA/r/HORGhyQX3Ba.js"}}}
1

I am at a loss... I'm not sure what to do here.

Where it gets really weird, is that sometimes the ?id=1 URL will fail too - but usually only after trying to send others...

Comment: It seems pretty self explanatory...